# operand type mismatch for `mov'

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, x86-64, inline-assembly

I want the eflags values, but I get the error

```
operand type mismatch for `mov'
```

Here is my code:

```
int a0 = 0, b0 = 1; short c0;
//  asm("cmp %1, %2\npushf\npop ax\nmov ax, $0": "=r" (c0): "r" (a0), "r" (b0));
asm("cmp %1, %2\n lahf\n mov %%ax, $0": "=r" (c0): "r" (a0), "r" (b0): "ax");
```

I also tried with movb ah but same error.

Comment: Use `"=a"(c0)` instead of `"=r"` to tell the compiler the result is in `RAX/EAX/AX/AL` in the first place, no MOV required.  Any time your inline asm starts or ends with a MOV, you're probably writing it inefficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code:

1. The `$` prefix indicates an immediate.  `mov %ax, $0` attempts to move `ax` to the immediate `0`, this is nonsensical.  Perhaps you meant to write `%0` instead, indicating `c0`?
2. If we replace `mov %%ax, $0` with `mov %%ax, %0`, the second problem is that `c0` is an `int`, thus `%0` is replaced with some 32 bit register, so you get something like `mov %ax, %ecx`.  This is wrong, too as both operands to `mov` must have the same size. You can fix this by making `c0` an `unsigned char` and changing `mov %%ax, %0` to `mov %%ah, %0`.

Anyway, using a `mov` in inline assembly is usually wrong but here it's hard to avoid as you can't easily tell gcc to expect `c0` in the `ah` register.

Comment: You can use register variable, e.g. `register unsigned char flags asm("ah");`. However `gcc` seems to have a bug and uses `al`. `clang` works.